# React component. Render specific element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx, react-props

Currently I've a component **User**, which renders 2 element -> **username** and **avatar**.
I'm getting the username and avatar perfectly, but I want to view only the **username** only

Is there any way to fetch only the **username** element ? Not with a profile picture.

```
//User component
const User = ({ username, profilePic }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Avatar name='user' src={profilePic.profile.image} alt="user_image" ml="5"/>
      <Heading size={'sm'} ml="5">{username.username}</Heading>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};


// Content Page
{group.members.map(member => {
 return <React.Fragment key={member.id}>
    <User username={member.user} profilePic={member.user}/>
      </React.Fragment>
 })}
```

Comment: If you don't want the `<Avatar>` element, just remove it?

Comment: I'm using the user component in some places, which require the <Avatar> element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an extra prop `renderAvatar` and only display the avatar if the boolean is `true` with conditional rendering.

```
const User = ({ username, profilePic, renderAvatar }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {renderAvatar && <Avatar name='user' src={profilePic.profile.image} alt="user_image" ml="5"/>}
      <Heading size={'sm'} ml="5">{username.username}</Heading>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

You could use it like this.

```
<User username={member.user} profilePic={member.user} renderAvatar={false} />
<User username={member.user} profilePic={member.user} renderAvatar={true} />
```

Or just create a component that only renders the `Heading`.

```
const UserWithoutAvatar = ({ username }) => {
  return <Heading size={'sm'} ml="5">{username.username}</Heading>
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to conditionally render based on whether or not `profilePic` is provided at all.  For example:

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    { profilePic ?
        <Avatar name='user' src={profilePic.profile.image} alt="user_image" ml="5"/>
      : null
    }
    <Heading size={'sm'} ml="5">{username.username}</Heading>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Then if you just don't provide `profilePic` it will be `undefined`:

```
<User username={member.user} />
```

---

As an aside, the code seems to be generating confusion around naming.  For example:

```
{username.username}
```

A property called "username" implies that it is a string representing the user's name.  But in this case `username` is an object containing a property called `username`?  Does *that* property contain a string?  Or another object?

Or here:

```
<User username={member.user} profilePic={member.user}/>
```

What is `member.user`?  Is it a username?  Is it a profile pic?  Somehow it's both?

Clarity is important.  If what you're actually passing to the component is a *user object* then call it that:

```
<User user={member.user} />
```

Alternatively, if the component is expecting a literal value for `username` and a literal value for `profilePic` then pass it those values:

```
<User username={member.user.username} profilePic={member.user.profile.image} />
```

Don't confuse your semantics.  Confusion leads to bugs.